# EncodeNameReplacements wildcard replacement happening before space-to-hyphen replacement

Tags: configuration

I'm encountering a problem that appears to be caused because I have a folder that contains both a wildcard item, and an item with a space in the name.  When I have an item with no space in it, it resolves just fine, but as soon as that space is in there, it starts trying to resolve it via the wildcard item.

I found this blog article, which discusses this exact issue: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/01/sitecore-81-encode-name-replacements.html

The blog article mentions that there is a support fix out there to resolve this, but for the life of me I can't find it.  I don't think updating our version of Sitecore is in the cards just yet, so I think this is my best option... if I could find it.

Can anyone out there help point me in the right direction?  Or perhaps knows of another solution I haven't stumbled across yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should ask Sitecore Support for the bugfix. You can refer to issue number 452602 (I'll add it to the blog). The fix should include a dll and a config file patching the ItemResolver.

The issue that was fixed with this patch can be reproduced like this:

1. Take a folder with a wildcard item in it
2. Create another item in that folder with a space in it
3. Follow a link to that item by the sitecore generated url (with a '-' instead of the space)
4. You will be taken to the wildcard item instead of the item you actually wanted

Sitecore Support can be reached on https://support.sitecore.net. The patch will replace the ItemResolver:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <patch:attribute name="type" value="Sitecore.Support.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Support.452602" />
</processor>
```

The dll itself is patching the constructor of the ItemResolver by adding a new `ContentItemPathResolver`. They changed the `DoResolveItem` method of the underlying `ItemPathResolver` to take wildcard items into account.